# PHP Parse this string

Tags: php, json

I'm getting the following sample string through post parameter. I need to get the key value pair from the data to process further. I've used

```
json_decode($data)
```

But it throws an error. I copied the string into jsonlint and validated. The string is a valid `json`

```
{
    "724361997575090":"https:\/\/z-n.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-h.ak\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/1904241_724361997575090_405663037_n.jpg?oh=6d847393648314f498b0ed5ddec339ca&oe=567A30F3&__gda__=1450240543_9f7147a5699bb9ce03747f5b9f4785f7",
    "10201722174609862":"https:\/\/z-n.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-d.ak\/hphotos-ak-xpf1\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/996939_10201722174609862_1085044118_n.jpg?oh=43f8044e9b52940c8b6e8bcdf936b139&oe=567D8587&__gda__=1450242029_a3ffb1833c84aabafd50b947963016f4",
    "653561304732935":"https:\/\/z-1-scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xfp1\/v\/t1.0-9\/s130x130\/10262274_653561304732935_4287650319995492122_n.jpg?oh=17d70cf9ec426d0f20070276d626e3ae&oe=567622FD",
    "785636858147560":"https:\/\/z-n.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-g.ak\/hphotos-ak-xtf1\/v\/t1.0-0\/s130x130\/224598_785636858147560_1779521948992015329_n.jpg?oh=8ba4a34102ac9647d70631a2b3b07ef3&oe=5682CF08&__gda__=1450077117_42060c2c51c7dedffc2a12d67a09dddb",
    "10152196967129315":"https:\/\/z-1-scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xft1\/v\/t1.0-9\/s130x130\/10364042_10152196967129315_4825955816401790627_n.jpg?oh=bac0bfcdc4caac23cdbcbf29d9b8e6cb&oe=565FDFA5",
    "504111853031524":"https:\/\/z-1-scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xtf1\/v\/t1.0-9\/s130x130\/1514596_504111853031524_503900941_n.jpg?oh=fe73e70cfd85334374a1c50baabb738e&oe=567DAB84",
    "553468811388609":"https:\/\/z-n.ak.fbcdn.net\/sphotos-b.ak\/hphotos-ak-xpa1\/v\/t1.0-9\/s130x130\/935949_553468811388609_410272599_n.jpg?oh=5c6f5d197f01867b7991c2ed0ec5d33c&oe=566E137D&__gda__=1451227136_598cffb867c87e771f21b2ec6d591c2d"
}
```

Can someone help me on getting the key, value from the above sample?

Error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Comment: Don't you think the error could help ?

Comment: Post the error being thrown...

Comment: Though the provided json in this question works. https://3v4l.org/Joeco

Comment: Also, please show where you assign the JSON to $data. I think you may have escaping issues.

Comment: You probably want `$array = json_decode($data, true);` and then do `echo $array['553468811388609'];`

Comment: Why downvotes? Am assigning it from key value pair in android-java

Comment: Can you please show us full code and error ?

Comment: Downvotes because "an error" is not the most helpful description of the problem.

Comment: @Downvoters Please explain..

Comment: @ling.s it's already been explained why you are being downvoted. Did you try my above comment?

Comment: @crypticツ You are correct. It is working now. Post as answer

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the second parameter of json_decode. If true, it will return an array, if false (by default) it will return a StdClass.

You should use the second parameter to true in your case.

Alternatively, you can embrace the fact that it returns an object and write : `$object->553468811388609`

Comment: Maybe `$object -> {'553468811388609'}` ?